# Cannot import pip installed module that is in path

Tags: python-3.x, pip, path, package

I have read the similar questions and their answers - either environment problems, multiple python interpreters or faulty paths. I did not find a solution.

I have made a package and uploaded it to PyPi - pywindowframes.

I have only 1 python interpreter installed (python 3.9.0) on windows 10, not using any virtual environment.

```
python - m pip install pywindowframes

or

pip install pywindowframes
```

Successfully installs the package.

```
[main.py]

import sys
print(sys.path)

import pywindowframes
```

```
[output]

"C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" C:/world_editor/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\world_editor\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pywindowframes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywindowframes'
['C:\\world_editor', 'C:\\world_editor',
'C:\\Users\\censored\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip', 
'C:\\Users\\censored\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
'C:\\Users\\censored\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\censored\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39', 
'C:\\Users\\censored\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
```

I can confirm that 'C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages' contains my package in the following folder:

pywindowframes-0.12.dist-info

- INSTALLER
- METADATA
- RECORD
- REQUESTED
- top_level
- WHEEL

```
pip uninstall pywindowframes
```

successfully uninstalls the package from that same folder.

In PyCharm, my package is even listed in the package list under the "Python Interpreter" tab under the Python interpreter I am currently using (Python 3.9).

Is it a problem with the dist itself?
Is it a problem with the **init** file?
Why isn't it found when it is present in a folder in path?

Comment: I am on Linux and when I download that package it doesn't contain any py files or manifest where to download them.  Not an expert on pip but that doesn't look right to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package pywindowframes appears to be broken.  There are no .py files in the package, nor does it have a manifest that points to said files.

Comment: Broken as in cannot be imported - or broken as in you can import it but it needs fixing?

Comment: It doesn't look like a valid package at all.  I am Linux but did `pip download pywindowframes` which lead me to that conclusion.  Have you tried running `pip install -vvv pywindowframes`.  Maybe it tells you what it does (something different than what I observed)?

Comment: How stupid of me. There are no actual .py-files!

Answer (score 0):

Pls verify your pip version as well just to make sure

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Pycharm using same Python version and environment with your Win10. You can check this interpreter settings in Pycharm. Also, I suggest you to install any package in there in Windows OS.